# Make listener and not call the function. Show and hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

```
<a onclick="showhide('1');">asd1</a>
<a onclick="showhide('2');">asd2</a>
<a onclick="showhide('3');">asd3</a>

<div class="hide" id="1">asd1</div>
<div class="hide" id="2">asd2</div>
<div class="hide" id="3">asd3</div>

<script>
    function showhide(id){
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(id);
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
            for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            divid.style.display = "block";
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(divid).offset().top}, 'slow');
        } 
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I`m doing this to show and hide divs. How can i do to make a listener and not to call the function in every a?

Comment: the line `if (document.getElementById) {` is going to cause some problems. Also, this question has been asked millions of times. Search for it.

Comment: are the number is the function (1,2,3) are always according to number in the innerHTML (asd1,asd2,asd3) ?

Comment: @pattmorter In the olden days (IE3, Netscape Navigator) that was the way to check if a browser supported document.getElementById or if you needed to use some other technique like document.all.  This is irrelevant nowadays, but it won't cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, you can just use the index instead

```
<a href="#" class="myAnchor">asd1</a>
<a href="#" class="myAnchor">asd2</a>
<a href="#" class="myAnchor">asd3</a>

<div class="hide">asd1</div>
<div class="hide">asd2</div>
<div class="hide">asd3</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.myAnchor').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.hide').hide().eq( $('.myAnchor').index(this) ).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3CZ5/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) jquery method